# GO zip.NewWriter() creating empty zip archives

Tags: go, zip

I have the following function I'v tried to simplify to just adding a single file to a .zip archive.

Whatever I try, the resulting .zip file has no files listed in it.  The size of the archive is correct.  But when I try to extract all (windows), the archive is empty.

go version go1.10.1 windows/amd64

```
func Zip(src string, dst string) error {
    destinationFile, err := os.Create(dst)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    myZip := zip.NewWriter(destinationFile)
    file := `C:\MA\testing\cldeploy-local.json`
    zipFile, err := myZip.Create(file)

    fsFile, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(zipFile, fsFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = myZip.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

When I extract the file an error message appears: The compressed (zipped) Folder ... is invalid.

Comment: From the zip documentation: [the file name] `must be a relative path, not start with a drive letter (such as "C:"), and must use forward slashes instead of back slashes`

Comment: that did it!  also had to remove the first forward slash.  testing/cldeploy-local.json .

Comment: Also don't forget to close all files you open, conveniently done with `defer`.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @JimB: file needs to be added as relative path
only forward slashes. can not start with slash

```
func Zip(src string, dst string) error {
    destinationFile, err := os.Create(dst)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    myZip := zip.NewWriter(destinationFile)
    file := `C:\MA\testing\cldeploy-local.json`

        // file needs to be added as relative path
        // only forward slashes. can not start with slash
        relPath := strings.TrimPrefix(file, filepath.Dir(src))
        relPath = strings.Replace(relPath, `\`, `/`, -1)
        relPath = strings.TrimLeft(relPath, `/`)

    zipFile, err := myZip.Create(relPath)

    fsFile, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(zipFile, fsFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = myZip.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.
Zipfile created, but empty if you open it with Windows Explorer. But if you open it with 7-zip filename looks like

Actual:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\products_list_432735630.zip\C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp
Expected
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\products_list_432735630.zip\

[image]

So if zip file and CSV file in one folder you must use relative path.
For Example

```
relativeFilename := filepath.Base(csvFile.Name())
zippedFile, err := zipper.Create(relativeFilename)
```